# How to query XML data in ClickHouse

Tags: xml, clickhouse, dbt

**Problem**
I want to migrate a data warehouse running in Postgres to *ClickHouse* and some of the source data is stored in XML format. I am using *dbt-core* to perform transformations on top of the ingested source data and the current staging models extract data from *XML*: I am looking for XML functions or any tips to handle that in *ClickHouse*.

Any thoughts?

I have been looking for XML functions within the documentation with no luck.

Comment: Try powershell : https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/postgresql-ado-powershell.rst

Comment: Thanks @jdweng but ClickHouse does not integrated with Poweshell, so you proposed solution is out of scope.

Comment: Click house is a HTTP Request/Response and you can use Invoke-Request in PS to communicate with ClickHouse : https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/http

Comment: This will still not solve the problem, as the XML needs to be extracted from dbt (i.e. SQL)

Comment: First get the response where the body is xml (a string).  Then parse the string response.